# What is this coordinate system from ESRI and how do I convert it to regular coordinates for GeoJSON Mercator?

Tags: leaflet, esri-geodatabase, lambert-conformal-conic

I downloaded the ArcGIS health region boundaries file in ESRI Lambert Conformal Conic format here: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/82-402-x/2018001/hrbf-flrs-eng.htm

Using mapshaper.org I exported the data to GeoJSON but the coordinates are not a system that I recognize, it looks like:

```
[-8650999.06360543,5474465.5029140925],[-8650958.754519965,5474511.452623501]
```

How do I convert these ESRI files to GeoJSON I can use with Leaflet maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download QGIS and load the Shapefile as a layer in QGIS.

Then, export the layer to GeoJSON, and switch the CRS to 4326/WGS 84

[image]

Since the source coordinate system is known (EPSG 3347), QGIS can do the transformation to EPSG 4326/WGS84.

It will be ready for Leaflet at that point.

Comment: Thanks! Will note for future readers of this using Mac OSX, import via `Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer`. To export right click on layer with features and select `Export > Save Features As...`

Comment: Great! Good luck up there (from one Canadian to another)

Comment: Heh no kidding, ironically this is for a COVID-19 project. BTW I simplified the vectors and resulting file is here: https://gist.github.com/crockpotveggies/03665aa9d55aeed11eb1d5ff7f1156dc

Comment: @crockpotveggies figured it would be... get in touch if you need anything else. We do a lot of leaflet mapping, and our developer is super sharp. My email is in my bio.

Comment: Thanks too! Just what I was looking for to get Statscan Arcinfo boundaries into geojson format for Leaflet map to visualize COVID-19 confirmed cases by Canadian provincial health regions [link](https://sitrucp.github.io/canada_covid_health_regions/)

Comment: @curtisp fantastic! that looks great! Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 1):

- First, load your arcGIS file through: layer->Add Layer -> Add vector layer
  [image: load ArcGIS file]
- Then export the vertices through: Vector -> Geometry -> Extract Vectors
  [image: export Vector]
- Next, export the vertices layer through: right click on vertices -> export -> save feature as
  [image]
- Then set the settings:
  format : csv
  CRS : EPSG:4326
  layer options -> GEOMETRY:AS_XY